# Generating both a library and binary from a single C source

Tags: c, compilation

I have a C source file with a main function and some other functions. Something like:

```
#include "stdlib.h"

int program(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    return program(argc, argv);
}
```

I know how to compile this to produce a binary.

**Is there a way to compile this into an object file with the `main` symbol/function omitted?**

I understand that I could accomplish my goal by splitting `main` into its own file, but suppose I don't want to do that.

Comment: Make `main()` conditional by putting it between `#ifdef WHATEVER`...`#endif`. And define WHATEVER only when building an executable.

Comment: This would work, but I'm still curious about whether gcc/clang have mechanisms for omitting symbols in general, or omitting main in particular, without modifying the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, having a definition of `main()` in a library is not a problem because the linker would only use it if there were no `main()` in any non-library binary. That can even be used to advantage, to include a default `main()`. See, for example, the Posix standard `-ll` library used with `lex` (or `-lfl` if you use flex).

If you really want to ensure that the symbol is not available for resolution, you can remove the symbol from the library. There are tools for manipulating binary files, which vary from system to system. For example, take a look at the `--strip-symbol` option of [objcopy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objcopy.1.html). (That doesn't remove the compiled code; it just makes it unresolvable.)

Comment: Is there a specific rule in C which excepts `main` from ODR rule?

Comment: @sergeyA: no, since the ODR is part of C++, not C. :-) But libraries are not part of the C standard at all, so once you use libraries you are in implementation-defined territory. And every library implementation I know of allows libraries to contain symbols already defined by the executable.

Comment: I am not familiar with C, but in C++ ODR is for 'application', which includes libraries. So in C++ this solution would be illegal.

Comment: @SergeyA: You might be right, but this question is tagged "C". However, I'm not convinced. [basic.def.odr]/10 says "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used." Fair enough. But [lex.phases] phase 9 is: "All external entity references are resolved. Library components are linked to satisfy external references to entities not defined in the current translation. All such translator output is collected into a program..." which seems to say that library components are not used to satisfy references to entities which are defined...

Comment: ... Whether or not that was the intent of the standard (and I personally think it was), it is certainly the behaviour of the linkers you and I use every day. As an additional point, the standard explicitly allows TUs to define certain names defined in the standard library, but I don't think that's relevant except as an example of why its useful to allow the TU to define a name which could be resolved from a library...

Comment: As a final quibble, I looked through the C++ standard and I didn't see any provision which says "`main()` is considered to be ODR-used." As far as I can see, `main()` is not normally ODR-used by any program because it is not legal to explicitly call `main`, so it will only appear as a definition.

Answer (score 1):

A library is simply an archive of object modules - to omit `main()` it must either be in a separate object module which you then simply omit from the library build, or you use conditional compilation so that it is omitted at *compile time*.

In fact if `main` were in a separate object module it would not matter whether it were not omitted since any definition in a directly linked object module would override any static library definition, so the library definition would only be used if it were not redefined.  I am not sure whether this will work if `main()` is defined in a module containing other symbols that are referenced in the binary, but nothing bad will happen if you try it other than a duplicate symbol error.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to compile this into an object file with the main
>   symbol/function omitted?

So you don't want symbol main in your object files.
This might be one way.

**file.c**

```
#include "stdlib.h"

int program(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]);
    int b = atoi(argv[2]);
    return a + b;
}

int not_main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    exit(0);
}
```

and then compile
[gcc]

> gcc file.c -o file -e not_main -nostartfiles

**SYMBOL TABLE:**

```
0000000000000238 l    d  .interp                0000000000000000              .interp
0000000000000254 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id     0000000000000000              .note.gnu.build-id
0000000000000278 l    d  .gnu.hash              0000000000000000              .gnu.hash
0000000000000298 l    d  .dynsym                0000000000000000              .dynsym
00000000000002e0 l    d  .dynstr                0000000000000000              .dynstr
0000000000000302 l    d  .gnu.version           0000000000000000              .gnu.version
0000000000000308 l    d  .gnu.version_r         0000000000000000              .gnu.version_r
0000000000000328 l    d  .rela.plt              0000000000000000              .rela.plt
0000000000000360 l    d  .plt                   0000000000000000              .plt
0000000000000390 l    d  .text                  0000000000000000              .text
00000000000003f0 l    d  .eh_frame_hdr          0000000000000000              .eh_frame_hdr
0000000000000418 l    d  .eh_frame              0000000000000000              .eh_frame
0000000000200e78 l    d  .dynamic               0000000000000000              .dynamic
0000000000200fd8 l    d  .got                   0000000000000000              .got
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment               0000000000000000              .comment
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*                  0000000000000000              file.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*                  0000000000000000              
0000000000200e78 l     O .dynamic               0000000000000000              _DYNAMIC
00000000000003f0 l       .eh_frame_hdr          0000000000000000              __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000200fd8 l     O .got                   0000000000000000              _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000201000 g       .got                   0000000000000000              _edata
00000000000003d5 g     F .text                  0000000000000019              not_main
0000000000000390 g     F .text                  0000000000000045              program
0000000000201000 g       .got                   0000000000000000              _end
0000000000201000 g       .got                   0000000000000000              __bss_start
0000000000000000       F *UND*                  0000000000000000              atoi@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000000000       F *UND*                  0000000000000000              exit@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to compile this into an object file with the main symbol/function omitted?

Yes, by using [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) tricks and/or [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to the compiler.

Change your C code (in your file `mycode.c`) to contain:

```
#ifdef HAVE_MAIN
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    return program(argc, argv);
}
#endif
```

Then, to get only an object file `mycode.o`, compile as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g mycode.c -c -o mycode.o` (if using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/))

To get the entire program `myprog`, compile it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -DHAVE_MAIN mycode.c -o myprog`

You could (avoiding any `#ifdef HAVE_MAIN`) even compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -Dmain=mymain -c mycode.c` to get the `main` function renamed, by preprocessing, as `mymain` (and then it is losing its magical status of "entry point").

However, doing that is considered bad taste (not very readable code). You'll better put your `main` in a different [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) and compile it only when you want a whole program. And quite often, a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) (or an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable)) is made from *several* translation units (each compiled into some [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file); the set of object files gets [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) together). You'll practically use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), etc...) to build it.